# Problem with turtle module in MacOsMojave

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics

I would like to understand this fact : when I use turtle module in Python with this code for example :

```
turtle.forward(10)turtle.done()
```

my Mac restarts directly. I don't know why.

What about thinking ?